# How to split string with special characters multiple times or in a continuous manner in C

Tags: c, string, split

I have the following string,

```
#98727,72000,2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#,
```

& am looking to split this entire string with special character `#`. In order to get the four `#` separated string sets.

After that these separated string sets need to be split using `,` to get values like eg: 98727 alone.

I've finished separating first set of values using `#` & `,` with the below code. But, it doesn't separating the second set. What am I missing in this set of code to separate all sets & its values?

```
char buffer[] = "#18115,72000,2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#";      

    char *ptr = &buffer;
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok(ptr,""); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ","))
    {
          printf("Set: %s\r\n", p);
          char *n;                
          for (n = strtok(p,","); n != NULL; n = strtok(NULL, ","))
          {
                 printf("%s\r\n", n);            
          }             
    }
```

And getting an output like this:

```
Set: 18115,72000,2500,2450,2200,999999,999999

18115
72000
2500
2450
2200
999999
999999
```

Comment: "*split this entire string with special character #.*" the code you show doesn't.

Comment: Calls to `strtok()` may not be nested. Have a look at `strtok_r()` to overcome this limitation.

Comment: OT: BTW, this `char *ptr = &buffer;` should make the compiler issue a warning, as `&buffer` evaluates to `char**`, what `ptr` clearly isn't.  You want: `char *ptr = buffer;`. Arrays are decayed to the address of their 1st element when being assigned.

Comment: @alk sorry for the typo.                                    char *p;
for (p = strtok(ptr,"#"); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, "#"))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of first splitting by occurrences of `#` and then by that of `,`, you could split by occurrence of `#` or `,` at once using [`strpbrk()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk).

You could do something like

```
char str[]="#98727,72000,2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#2500,2450,2200,999999,999999#,";
char *p;
char num_str[20][10];
int i=0;
for(p=str; (p=strpbrk(p, "#,"))!=NULL; )
{
    while(*(++p)=='#' || *p==',');  
    if(*p=='\0')
    {
        break; //input string over
    }
    sscanf(p, "%9[^#,]", num_str[i++]);
    printf("\n%s", num_str[i-1]);
}
```

A pointer `p` is maintained which points to the next `#` or `,` to be examined in the input string. `strpbrk()` is used to find this pointer value.

`strpbrk()` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of any character of a string in another string.

After finding the value of `p`, it is incremented so that it points to the character after the `#` or `,` and if this character is also one of those, you keep on incrementing till another character is found. If this character is the nul character denoting the end of string, we exit the outer loop.

`sscanf()` is used to extract the characters till the next `#` or `,`.

`%9[^#,]` reads till but not including the next `#` or `,`.

P.S: The `\r` in `printf("Set: %s\r\n", p);` is superfluous.